# Add new cursor in Sublime 3 under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, sublime-text-3

In Sublime manual `Alt`+`Shift`+`Down` or `Up` stands for adding new cursor, but when I press it nothing happens. I tried to find system binding for this combination, but it looks like unused in Ubuntu. Is there a way to make it work?